# Как работают классы обёртки Integer, String и остальные в Java

Tags: java

Я пытался найти ответы в гугле но так как я не очень то и смышленный в этом плане я не понял как поставить вопрос.

Суть в том, что при использовании, пускай и осуждённого, конструктора `Integer val = new Integer(1)`, значиение переменной `val` становится таким же как и аргумент использованный в конструкторе. Как такое сделать самому? Я просто путаюсь в коде файла `Integer.class`и ничего не могу разобрать. Кому не лень можете пожалуйста объяснить?

Comment: Не понятно. Объясните пож. что вы хотите добится конкретно? Сделать класс, который бы формировал объект равный переменной конструктора?

Comment: Вот ссылка на сырец https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java. Как вы можете видеть - значение, переданное в конструктор, хранится в поле

Comment: @Chubatiy иммено это. Я же сказал что не знаю как корректно поставить вопрос

Comment: @Chubatiy это я понял что значение хранится в поле, но я не понимаю как оно конкретно присваивается объектну и не надо обращатся через `fieldName.value`

Comment: Никак не присваивается. Грубо говоря данный класс рассматривайте как контейнер. То есть класс, содержащий переменную и набор методов по работе с ней. Это и есть так называемая обертка

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В общем насколько я понял экспериментальным и теоретическим путем, значение объекта присваивается переменной только если в классе-обёртке есть методы, без них оно возвращает просто объект.

Answer (score 0):

Integer val = new Integer(1)
создали класс обёртку над int после в кавычки положили значение. ето значение записалося через конструктор в переменную, ето присвоение сразу при объявлении и через конструктор; он не даст присвоить "невалидного значения" типа строка "1" также может определить последовательность и сопутствующие параметры. конструктор указывает как должен наполнятся клас и критерии или по умалчанию, или как вы скажете и никак подругому. Конструкторы вызываются при создании нового объекта данного класса. Конструкторы выполняют инициализацию объекта. 
`Integer val = new Integer(1);` // обьявили клас и переменную
`Integer val = new Integer();` // обьявили клас и переменную
`val = 1` // записали значение

Словом "new" Вы даете команду создать новый экземпляр класса.
Integer.class имеем привилегии класса.